# How do I find out an appointment is private?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Using office.js, is there a way to determine (only read) the sensitivity of an appointment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that we are actively working on and it will be in preview soon.